# How to properly use an if/else structure to animate new content from the right and get rid of old content by sliding to the left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", mouseOver1);

function mouseOver1(){

   document.getElementById("button1").style.color = "red";

}


document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", mouseOver); 


    function mouseOver(){ 

      document.getElementById("button2").style.color = "purple";
   }



$("#button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}); 

$("#button2").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});

   if($(".existing1-username-input-textbox").get(0).val()== "Micheal22" && $(".existing2-password-input-textbox").get(0).val()== "honor7thG")  
 {
        $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        $('.username-label').animate({'left': '-105%'}); 
        // but I want all the old content to slide to the left if username and password match above
        // then new content should slide in from the right. 

        });  
  
  }else{
  $(".existing1-username-input-textbox").firstChild.nodeValue="The existing username is not correct";
 
  $(".password-new-input-textbox").firstChild.nodeValue="The existing password is not correct"; 

  }
```

```css
.intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#para1 {
  padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px;
}

#para2 {
  padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
}

.username-label,
.password-label {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 300px;
 position: relative; 
 top: -70px; 
}

.existing1-username-input-textbox, 
.existing2-password-input-textbox
{
    top: -70px; 
     position: relative; 
      
}

#button1{ 
     background-color: #add8e6;
     margin-left: 390px; 
     position: relative; 
     top: -50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}

#button2{
  background-color: #add8e6;
  margin-left: -200px; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -30px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 

}


.Username-label1, 
.Password-label2,           
.Email-label3, 
.Repeat-Email-label4 
{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 300px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -70px; 
}
.username-new-input-textbox, 
.password-new-input-textbox, 
.email-new-input-textbox, 
.reenter-new-input-textbox{ 
  position: relative;
   top: -70px;
  margin-left: 20px; 

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Project</title>

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row top">
      <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
      <div class="login">
        <label class="username-label" for="username-part1">Username</label> &nbsp; 
         <input class="existing1-username-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
        <br/><br/>
        <label class="password-label" for="password-part2">Password</label> &nbsp; 
        <input class="existing2-password-input-textbox" type="password" value="" />
        <br/>
        <button id="button1">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>

      <div class= "new_customers_info">

        <label class="Username-label1" for="new-user-name-part-1">Username</label>
        <input class="username-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
         <br/><br/>

        <label class="Password-label2" for="password-new-part2">Password</label>
        <input class="password-new-input-textbox" type="password" value="" />
         <br/><br/>

        <label class="Email-label3" for="email-new">Email Address</label>
         <input class="email-new-input-textbox" type="text" value=""/>
          <br/><br/>

        <label class="Repeat-Email-label4" for="repeat-new-email">Repeat Email Address</label>
         <input class="reenter-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />

        <button id="button2">Create Account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <br/>
  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</div>
    <script src="Home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get my current content to slide to the left and bring in new content from the right (after clicking on button 1) when an existing student's username and password are correct, and if it's not correct display error messages that either the username or password isn't correct below each respective textbox .I am thinking about using an if/else condition. Also, how would I load the student's existing account information upon sliding it from the right, if I haven't created the content yet? If I already created the content to be slide in from the right, where do I hold that information until it's time to display that new content. Here is my code so far.

Comment: Your check for username and password will not work. Please assign some id to username and password input fields and then do `if(document.getElementById("username").value=="Micheal" && document.getElementById("password").value=="honor7thG")`. For JQuery animation you can follow : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: Thanks  @Nishesh Pratap.

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap, I can't do it with class selectors of the input text fields?  I thought I could.

Comment: Yes, you can do then you should use `$(".existing1-username-input-textbox").get(0).value` and `$(".existing2-password-input-textbox").get(0).value`

Comment: @ Nishesh Pratap I updated my code, but I am still having trouble with my if/else conditions.

Comment: **get()** function returns JS element, so instead of calling **val()** on that call **.value**

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap-Could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean you should use, `$(".existing1-username-input-textbox").get(0).value`

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap -Use $(".existing1-username-input-textbox").get(0).value && $(".existing2-password-input-textbox").get(0).value inside of the if condition?

Comment: Yup correct. These statements should be in if condition where you are checking username and password.

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap -Can u explain to me what I am doing wrong? Because when click on login button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below piece of code will execute when page get loaded and at that time username and password fields will be blank, so no event will get associated with login button :

```
if($(".existing1-username-input-textbox").get(0).val()== "Micheal22" && $(".existing2-password-input-textbox").get(0).val()== "honor7thG")  
{
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        $('.username-label').animate({'left': '-105%'}); 
        // but I want all the old content to slide to the left if username and password match above
        // then new content should slide in from the right. 

    });    
}else{
    $(".existing1-username-input-textbox").firstChild.nodeValue="The existing username is not correct";
    $(".password-new-input-textbox").firstChild.nodeValue="The existing password is not correct"; 
}
```

You should change this to below :

```
$('#button1').on('click', function () {
    if($(".existing1-username-input-textbox").get(0).value== "Micheal22" && $(".existing2-password-input-textbox").get(0).value== "honor7thG")  
    {
        $('.username-label').animate({'left': '-105%'}); 
        // but I want all the old content to slide to the left if username and password match above
        // then new content should slide in from the right. 
    }else{
        $(".existing1-username-input-textbox").firstChild.nodeValue="The existing username is not correct";
        $(".password-new-input-textbox").firstChild.nodeValue="The existing password is not correct"; 
    }
});
```

Now this will associate click event with login button on page load, so when you click login, it will first check the username and password, if matched then the animation part will take effect otherwise else part will execute.

Answer (score 1):

one quick way to do it is via JQuery's .animate function.

Here is a little fiddle with the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/f7VdQ/135/

```
$(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        $('.left').animate({'left': '-105%'});
        $('.right').animate({'left': '0px'});
    });

    $('p').on('click', function () {
        $('.left').animate({'left': '10'});
        $('.right').animate({'left': '105%'});
    });
})
```

PS.: If you dont want to the current content to be overlayed (that's an additional funcionallity of the fiddle) just dont use z-indexes on the CSS and also use relative positioning.

Comment: @MasterfonI- I updated my code, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work. Am not doing the if/else conditions right?